# Prove the equicontinuity of family of $C^1$ functions

Tags: functional-analysis, equicontinuity

I'm trying to solve the following exercise:

Let $I=[0, 1]  \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and consider the family
$$A= \{u \in C^1(I): ||u'||_{L^2} \leq 1 \}. $$
Prove that $A$ is a equicontinuous family.

Could somebody please give me a hint? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $u(x)=u(0)+\displaystyle\int\limits_0^xu'(t)dt$, $u(y)=u(0)+\displaystyle\int\limits_0^yu'(t)dt$, then $|u(x)-u(y)|=...$ (use Cauchy-Schwarz).

Comment: I'm sorry, I really can't figure out how Cauchy-Schwarz could get involved. How am I supposed to procede?

Comment: Without lose generality let $x<y$, then $|\int\limits_x^yu'(t)dt|\leq\sqrt{\int\limits_x^y1dt}\cdot\sqrt{\int\limits_x^y|x'(t)|^2dt}\leq\sqrt{y-x}\cdot\sqrt{\int\limits_0^1|x'(t)|^2dt}$.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I can see it.